# Alternative to using Azure Cloud service in a CSP subscription

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-fabric, azure-cloud-services, azureportal

Team,

I have a complete running cloud service application upgraded to latest Azure SDK version and unfortunately need to dump this into a CSP subscription. But I came to know that Azure CSP supports only the Azure Resource Manager model, the cloud service is a classic deployment model. So we cannot create a cloud service within a CSP subscription.

Is there any other alternative within Azure CSP to using "cloud service" so that we can migrate with minimal changes. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, here are some good reads on Microsoft Docs to help comparing the options available and make decisions based on your requirements:

(I mean requirements like Hosting features, Service Limits, 3rd party software installation and RDP access is required or not, Network isolation to a separate VNET is required or not, Cost considerations, minimum SLA, Regions available, instant deployment and auto-scaling, state management etc.):

1. [Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm)
2. [Decision tree for Azure compute services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree) (This one covers a big spectrum.. simple virtual machines, Batch, Functions, Containers, AKS, ServiceFabric)
3. [Criteria for choosing an Azure Compute Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-comparison)

Also know that when looking for alternatives, it's not uncommon to make use of multiple compute or other Azure service options by breaking up an older solution into parts at the time of such migration (for e.g. A serverless compute option like Azure Function + Service Fabric + something else if needed).

Generally speaking (and without knowing much about your application from your question currently), Azure App Service and Service Fabric could be considerations IMHO when migrating from an existing Cloud Service, but this is exactly where detailed requirements help you in decision making.

On a side note, here is a list of Azure Services available in CSP - [Available Azure services in Azure CSP](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=07&d1=01&y1=2012&m2=9&d2=11&y2=2018)

Comment: Hi rohit, Thanks for your reply. Ours is a MVC application and it contains a Azure cloud service project which has a single webrole. We have chosen to Azure app service as this seems to cost effective and also with less architectural changes. Any suggestions regarding this. Also, do you have any info/guide to help us convert this webrole into web app?